# When error handling in Java, should I catch Exception to catch all exceptions or individually catch exceptions?

Tags: java, exception

Say I have code that throws many different exceptions:

```
thisThrowsIllegalArgumentException("this is an illegal argument");
thisThrowsIOException("C:/Users/Admin/Documents/does-not-exist.txt");
thisThrowsIndexOutOfBoundsException(Integer.MAX_SIZE + 1);
thisThrowsNullPointerException(null);
...etc
```

These errors need to be handled. So, I have two options. I can either:

Catch each exception individually, like so:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    System.err.println("Something went wrong.");
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println("Something went wrong.");
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException) {
    System.err.println("Something went wrong.");
} catch (NullPointerException) {
    System.err.println("Something went wrong.");
}
```

...or catch a general `Exception`, like so:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.err.println("Something went wrong.");
}
```

I understand that in Java 7, you can simply write:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (IllegalArgumentException | IOException | IndexOutOfBoundsException | NullPointerException ex) {
    System.err.println("Something went wrong.");
}
```

However, I am restrained to Java 6.

What is the best practice for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

General approach:

- catch the narrowest exception class possible if the catch block is handling the problem
- if the caller is to handle the problem, declare `throws`. You may catch (still narrowest possible) and throw a domain specific exception instead
- if you can't handle the problem, but there is "no caller" because your code is the top layer in the call stack, catch Exception because your code is the last chance to take action

Answer (score 6):

Catching `Exception` in application code is usually wrong.  Sometimes its unavoidable, but if it is avoidable, you should avoid it.

Note that:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    System.err.println("Something went wrong.");
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println("Something went wrong.");
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException) {
    System.err.println("Something went wrong.");
} catch (NullPointerException) {
    System.err.println("Something went wrong.");
}
```

and

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.err.println("Something went wrong.");
}
```

do very different things!  The latter catches all `RuntimeException`s (unchecked exceptions) as well as the checked exceptions you expect to catch!  To have the same semantics, you'd have to catch and rethrow `RuntimeException` before `Exception`, but then would still have to explicitly handle the unchecked exceptions you want to handle, like this:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
    System.err.println("Something went wrong.");
} catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException) {
    System.err.println("Something went wrong.");
} catch (NullPointerException) {
    System.err.println("Something went wrong.");
} catch (RuntimeException e) { 
    throw e; 
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Something went wrong.");
}
```

Which kind of defeats the point, you wanted the code to be more compact.

You should write the multi-exception catch and plan to coalesce the catch clauses when you upgrade to Java 7 (a good IDE will help you find them all and convert them for you.)

Answer (score 0):

It always depends what you want to do. In some (most) cases you want to handle exceptions by yourself. If you can group them because you just want to print them, then (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();} is fine.

For writing files for example, when it throws an IOException you want to do handle it directly.

It may be possible that you want to create a new file and reexecute the method or such.

.. It always depends what you want to do.

Another example:

If you create and connect a socket you can either create an (Exception e) or you can handle SocketTimeOutException by yourself and just reconnect the socket. You can also catch the IOException and handle a proper disconnect by cleaning up your ressources and cache the failed package somewhere for resending later.

Answer (score 0):

As was said before, it depends on what you want to do and your particular circumstance.

Some exceptions you want to handle to continue the program, and those are ones that you want to give special attention to maybe in order to give a certain kick back to the user to request a new input or some sort of change.

If you don't yet know how you want to handle a certain exception, you can just catch the general exception and report it.

In some cases such as a class with several methods, you could just throw all the exceptions out of each method an into the class and handle the exceptions one level higher.